# How can i get lazy load plugin to work without mouse interaction?

Tags: jquery-lazyload

Currently, I am using lazyload with infinite scroll. When users scroll to bottom of my page, I load new 'lazy' images but lazyload doesnt trigger image downloads until i have moved my mouse. Is there any way to force lazyload to download images and not wait for interaction from mouse to set the viewport?

http://cl.ly/image/1s2E2t1b1t3b

I am using this code:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"})
```

Comment: Infinite scrolling is "lazy loading" the content. Why lazy load images within lazy loaded content?

Comment: Cause we are infinte scroll loading 40 images...but only 10 show up on the screen at a time, so bandwidth saving and speed

Answer (score 1):

In the callback of your infinite scroll plugin trigger a scroll event programmatically.

```
$(window).trigger('scroll');
```